# Add date of send to Sendlog for every record?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, send-email

How would I go about adding the EventDate from the _sent table to the Sendlog for every campaign? Technically it doesn't have to be that exact value, but essentially it needs to be the date of send.

I've read about having an AMPscript Upsert function in the email content that would write to a field in the sendlog, but we would like to avoid having to add extra AMPscript in every one of our email contents (even if it is just a content area that is being pulled in)

Is there a blanket way to add the date of the send to every record in the sendlog?

Thanks!

Right after I typed this out, I had a thought. Would the date of the send be logged to a field in the sendlog with a type of date, with the default value set to the current date? With no values being passed to override the default, would this log the date of the send while it handles the other send logging too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can just add an `EventDate` column to your Send Log and have it default to Current Date.  That's the easiest.

You can also create an AMPScript variable in your email named `EventDate` and set the value manually.  It'll get recorded automatically in the Send Log as long as the variable name matches the Send Log column name:

```
%%[
var @EventDate
set @EventDate = Now()
]%%
```